# private message system - mysqli from mysql

Tags: php

I'm new at php and I followed this youtube : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ8DpIbD9Ps
in order to build the conversations.php script. I made a littel adjustment's from mysql to mysqli. I don't get the same result as in minute 10:06 of the video. It doesn't display me the conversations list. I can't find where my error is.

```
   <?php
        if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
          echo "Show messages!";  
        }  
        else {
            echo "<b>Select Conversation:</b>";
            $sql_k = "select 'hash', 'user_one','user_two' from message_group 
            where user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'";
            $get_con = mysqli_query($db,$sql_k);
            while ($run_con = mysqli_fetch_array($get_con)){
                 $hash = $run_con['hash'];
                 $user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
                 $user_two = $run_con['user_two'];
                 if ($user_one==$my_id) 
                 {
                     $select_id = $user_two;
                 } else {
                     $select_id = $user_one;
                 } 
                      $sqli = "Select 'username' from users where 
                      id='$select_id'";
                      $user_get = mysqli_query($db,$sqli);
                      $run_user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_get);
                      echo $run_user;
                      $select_username = $run_user['username'];
                      echo "<p><a href ='conversations.php?hash=$hash'>$select_username</a></p>";
                 }
            }   
        ?>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_object` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: @HamzaRashid he's accessing the result as an array. Why would he want to fetch it as an object?

Comment: where did I quate my table names? message_group or users?

Comment: I've added explanation as well as example for understanding.

Comment: `$sql_k = "select 'hash', 'user_one','user_two'` - You're still doing the same error you did in another of your questions where you quickly ignored and didn't bother replying to that comment or any other comment I posted for past questions. If you want to make your code run; simple; check for errors, you have many. Btw; I ended up deleting that comment about the `'hash'` column; I had my reasons. Maybe you have something against me; I don't know.

Comment: @Fred-il, I have taken your words to my attention. I'm just new at php and asking questions about this. Of course I have nothing against you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To answer your question:*

1. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array`. It is recommended syntax to avoid getting extra data in query result. Improves efficiency in case of heavy weight queries. Moreover it avoids confusion for early learners.
2. Use back ticks on column names instead of single quotes.

   SELECT `hash`, `user_one`, `user_two` FROM message_group WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'
3. When fetching data in case of `mysqli_fetch_assoc` use single quotes like you are already doing i.e. `$run_con['hash']`

---

**Usage of `mysql_fetch_***

Using `mysqli_fetch_row`, data is available in indexed array.

```
$hash = $run_con[0];
$user_one = $run_con[1];
$user_two = $run_con[2];
```

Using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, data is available in associated array.

```
$hash = $run_con['hash'];
$user_one = $run_con['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_con['user_two'];
```

Using `mysqli_fetch_array`, data is available in indexed as well as associative array. Following lines of code will result in same value storing in `$hash`.

```
$hash = $run_con[0];
$hash = $run_con['hash'];
```

Using `mysqli_fetch_object`, data is available as object.

```
$hash = $run_con->hash;
$user_one = $run_con->user_one;
$user_two = $run_con->user_two;
```

Side note: `mysqli_fetch_arary` is not recommended as it brings back extra data, which is same data in indexed array as well associated array format (which is usually not required.)

Comment: If you want the result as an associative array you should use mysqli_fetch_assoc, not mysqli_fetch_object

Comment: And another thing, this is probably not were the problem is, because as default mysqli_fetch_array will return the results both indexed and with the column name as key, so both indexed and associative. So changing to mysqli_fetch_assoc would not change anything, other then a smaller array without the indexed (0, 1....) data. You should try to var_dump($run_user); and see what result you get from that query. Does it return the expected result?

Comment: Well, you right. I've changed array to object and the list of conversations still doens't display in page.